# How to handle/ queue multiple ajax posts?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have an index view in a Rails 3.2 app that displays a delete button next to each record.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", object, method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'delete' %>
```

I had originally created a destroy.js.erb file to remove the object when it is destroyed. However, this was not giving the snappy and responsive experience I was looking for.

Instead, I set up this coffeescript function

```
jQuery ->
  if $('a.delete').length
    $("a.delete").click ->
      if confirm("Are you sure?")
        row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0)
        $.post @href,
          _method: "delete"
        , null, "script"
        $(row).hide()
        false
      else
        #they clicked no.
        false
```

This works well 99% of the time. But I'm finding some edge cases when a user rapidly deletes several objects in succession. While the objects are hidden, some don't appear to be properly deleted and are revealed again on a page reload.

Is there a better way to accomplish this, or to queue my .post requests so that I can be 100% confident that they do all complete?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to queue tasks, you might want to consider the delayed_job gem, https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.

As for a better way of keeping items slated for deletion off the page, you could combine delayed_job with a "pending_deletion" boolean field on your model. When a user indicates that an object is to be deleted, have it tagged, submit the delete job, and then run your Coffeescript function to hide it. Your initial query before drawing the view could be modified to include objects where pending_delete != true. This feels to me like a bit much but if your deletion process is slow or your queue gets backed up frequently, it seems reasonable.

You might also (or alternatively) want to consider having your CoffeeScript function execute as the response to a controller action. If Object.delete returns true, the function runs and the object is hidden.

Comment: thanks subvertallchris. Is there anyway to queue the ajax requests within the browser though? My server side delete job is already optimized, and I am using queue_classic for long running tasks. There would be very little time saved between posting a destroy request or an update to a `pending_deletion` field in this case — both require a delay while a connection is established and sent. I'm looking for a very fast client side response to update the view, but need greater confidence that *all* destroy requests will make it through than my current set up is providing. Thanks for your ideas

Comment: I see! It seems to me that the only way you can really be sure that your destroy request is going through is to make `$(row).hide()` run based on a successful response from `$.post`. Unless I'm misreading your CoffeeScript or missing something, it looks like it attempts to make the post and then it hides the row, regardless of post's outcome. Or is there a delay in the post's response that prevents this from being an option?